# Workflow Error - Sharepoint logs

Tags: 2010, workflow, workflow-variable

I am encountering a strange behavior of custom workflows and cannot find any clue for it.

The error seems to be independent of the item data - even if the item data is the same, usually workflow works fine, sometimes it generates an error for the same data(Error occurred in [Workflow name]).

Maybe it is because workflow uses 'Store...' action and as far as I have found out this function is no longer available in SP2010.
Saving and publishing workflow with this actions does not result in any error, so I assume that SP2010 is compatible.

Is there anybody who can comment on such behavior? Is there any impact of 'Store..' action on workflows in the SP2010?